# saving audio files in django table(model)

Tags: django

I want to store audio files under an attribute 'soundsrc' in the model elementsound. A part of models.py is given below:

models.py(code snippet)

```
class elementsound(models.Model):
    cdid=models.IntegerField()
    soundsrc=models.FileField()
    sounddesc=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

how do i do that? what changes have to be made in settings.py? please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Setup `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in you `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In your `urls.py`, add:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Make sure to have `media` directory in your root directory.

If you want to upload images in forms, make sure to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `template`:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also, make sure in `views`, use:

```
form = Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

It will work.

Comment: Yes, both `images` and `audio` are `media_files`, so they will be stored as media files, all you need to change is in your `templates` to access these file, for image, we use `<img>` tag in templates, and for audio, use `<audio>` tag.

Comment: here FileField() would be used right? And are there going to be any parameters to it?

Comment: Yes, use `FileField()` for it, you can pass parameters as per your need like `upload_to` or other parameters, but these are optional and use them as per your need.